# Wordpress - adding a div to the index.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

In the past I have been putting a div in the index.php file of our wordpress site to display a list of our groups aims. The div created sits under the blog-feed div. After update Version 5.5.1 the index.php is different and doesn't seem to have an area for me to add this code as it now looks like this(see below).

Can you please tell me where I should now add this code or do I need to move it to another file?

-----------------------------------index php file --------------------------------------------------

```
*<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';*
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking in wp-content/themes/{your-theme} to make any edits you need. But the best practice is to make your own theme or a child theme that extends a third party theme. I would suggest researching child themes to do any customizing you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it doesn't tell me where the code I want to add should go.